# Frequent BSODs... BIOS settings?

Tags: windows-7, bios, bsod

I've been getting very frequent BSODs after putting together my new setup...

- Gigabyte GA-P55M-UD2
- Intel Core i5-760 2.8 GHz
- G.SKILL Ripjaws 8GB DDR3-1333 SDRAM
- OCZ Vertex 96GB SATA II SSD
- Hitachi 1TB 7200RPM SATA II HDD
- Sapphire Xtreme Radeon HD 5830 1GB GDDR5
- OCZ ModXStream Pro 600W modular PSU
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

I've attached a screenshot, which shows that ntoskrnl.exe (a frequent cause, not shown in BSV) and ntfs.sys are causes for this BSOD. Settings I've changed in the BIOS are changing the SATA mode to AHCI from IDE, enabling hard drive S.M.A.R.T. capabilities and changing the primary graphics adapter to PCI Express.

However, I'm still getting these BSODs and can't figure out the issue. Right before a BSOD, everything slowly freezes up, programs become non-responsive and some problems close spontaneously.

What do these BSODs mean and what do I do to prevent them from happening?

[image]

Comment: could you give [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) a shot? it tends to be a little more comprehensible than bluescreen view

Comment: Unfortunately WhoCrashed cannot read the dump file as I've restarted a couple times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer have these parts, but the motherboard was defective and ended up dying.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the main culprit for "this system just won't work right" is the crappy psu, but your unit seems ok-ish and oversized. The most common diagnostic I could think of:

> 1. Check for MB bios updates and see what issues are resolved. Update
>      the BIOS if needed.
> 2. Update to latest drivers.
> 3. Return the bios settings to their default. Just in case.
> 4. Check for updates for your SSD firmware. Apply them.
> 5. Check that all PSU connectors, Video card, RAM sticks, sata
>      connectors,coolers etc are properly plugged mounted and secured.
> 6. Run memtest86+ for a couple of hours to make sure your ram is
>      working ok.
> 7. Run Intel Burn Test a few times on very high. If it passes 5-10
>      tests, your CPU is stable. Monitor your cpu temp. If it passes 70
>      Celsius this can be the problem.
> 8. Run Furmark/Kombustor for a long time to test your VGA card.
>      Monitor your GPU temp. It better stay below 80 Celsius
> 9. Run Prime 95 on 3 threads and Kombustor for maximum power load.
> 10. Check the temperatures of your CPU and GPU under load. If they are
>       high - this may be the reason.

If your system passes the above the chances are that your hardware works fine and you don't have a faulty specimen for some of the components.

Return windows to clean install.

Then you move to disable all features in bios that can introduce instability cpu sleep states etc.

Comment: 1. BIOS is the lastest version
2. Drivers are the most recent
3. BIOS was running default until I tried to tweak settings.
4. Need to check...
5. It is in a tight case, but I will double check all the connections.
6. Did that... no errors.
7. Used Prime95... no errors, max 55 C.
8. Will do it... but idling 33 C only.
9. Will do it, but highly doubt power supply is not sufficient enough.
10. CPU is good, GPU should be good... will check.

Comment: Update: 4. SSD firmware needs to be updated; however, it is not detecting the drive properly, and the firmware update cannot complete. 7. Will be running 10 rounds of Intel Burn Test. 8. Will be running it shortly. 9. Also will be running it shortly. 10. Will find out after the previous two items.

Comment: Update: 4. Still not working for some reason. 7. Passed, max 67 C. 8. Passed, max 63 C. 9. Run... no problems. 10. Load temperatures are reasonable.

Comment: So  with mem, GPU and CPU working, not much left sadly. According to your MB spec you have two sata controllers- Intel And GB one. You can try move the drives from one to the other. Or/and to different ports on the same controller they are now.

Comment: I was using only the SATA ports running off the Intel controller. I've since switched the SSD and HDD to another machine and tried updating the firmware, but the SSD doesn't even show up on the list of drives. I've set my BIOS to IDE mode and followed the instructions, but it just seems that I can't upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if everything is seated correctly on your motherboard. If there's an occasional misconnection, you could easily get BSODs.

Last time I had a machine that was BSODing, a simple re-seating of the RAM sticks resolved it completely.